# How to set default permissions when creating a docker layer management file

Tags: linux, docker

This is a question about setting permissions for the /var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/lower path used for container management in docker.

By default, when creating a file in that path, the default permission is set to -rw-rw-rw-. At this time, w permission was set in the Other user's permissions, so it was pointed out as a security problem.

If so, is it possible to specify default creation permissions through Docker settings?

We confirmed that there is no problem with service operation when running the chmod -R 744 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/lower command, and confirmed in the official document that the lower path is read-only.

What I want is to have default file permission settings provided by Docker, rather than manually managing file permissions through the chmod command.

Comment: I'd recommend never ever touching those files.  Access the Docker filesystem layer only by running programs in containers.  There's no "default permission" for this directory, because it isn't intended to be user-visible.

Comment: I know that I have to be careful when dealing with that path. However, the path for which you want to change permissions (`/var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/lower`) has files that are treated as Read-Only in the official Docker documentation.

A link to a similar docker forum inquiry is attached( https://forums.docker.com/t/lowerdir-permissions/139327).